# java.lang.IllegalAccessException during Ant jwsc webservice build

Tags: web-services, ant, weblogic-10.x

I have a large application, part of which relies on a set of 3 webservices. I'm currently in the process of writing an Ant build script to build and package the application into an EAR file. When building the web sub-project for this application I use the `<jwsc>` task in Ant to compile the webservices. This causes an IllegalAccessException, as outlined in the stack trace below:

> ```
>  [jwsc] warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
>  [jwsc] JWS: processing module weboutput
>  [jwsc] Parsing source files
>  [jwsc] Parsing source files
>  [jwsc] 3 JWS files being processed for module weboutput
>  [jwsc] JWS: C:\dev\ir\irWeb\src\webservices\DailyRun.java Validated.
>  [jwsc] JWS: C:\dev\ir\irWeb\src\webservices\PendingRegistrationsSweep.java Validated.
>  [jwsc] JWS: C:\dev\ir\irWeb\src\webservices\RegistrationsGoLive.java Validated.
>  [jwsc] Compiling 6 source files to C:\DOCUME~1\KEVIN~1.BRE\LOCALS~1\Temp\_5l950r
>  [jwsc] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.6.0_23). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
>  [jwsc] java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader$AnnotationDefaultCompleter from class com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.attachAnnotationDefault(ClassReader.java:1128)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readMemberAttr(ClassReader.java:906)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readMemberAttrs(ClassReader.java:1027)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1490)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readClass(ClassReader.java:1586)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.readClassFile(ClassReader.java:1658)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.fillIn(ClassReader.java:1845)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.complete(ClassReader.java:1777)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:386)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:763)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.jvm.ClassReader.loadClass(ClassReader.java:1951)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.loadClass(Resolve.java:842)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Resolve.findIdentInPackage(Resolve.java:1011)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.selectSym(Attr.java:1921)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.visitSelect(Attr.java:1835)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCFieldAccess.accept(JCTree.java:1522)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribTree(Attr.java:360)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribType(Attr.java:390)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.attribImportType(MemberEnter.java:681)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.visitImport(MemberEnter.java:545)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCImport.accept(JCTree.java:495)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:387)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:399)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.visitTopLevel(MemberEnter.java:512)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:446)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.memberEnter(MemberEnter.java:387)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.MemberEnter.complete(MemberEnter.java:819)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol.complete(Symbol.java:386)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol.complete(Symbol.java:763)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:464)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:442)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:819)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:727)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:279)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:270)
>  [jwsc]     at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:69)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [jwsc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.Javac13.execute(Javac13.java:56)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1097)
>  [jwsc]     at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.DelegatingJavacTask$ExposingJavac.compile(DelegatingJavacTask.java:343)
>  [jwsc]     at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.DelegatingJavacTask.compile(DelegatingJavacTask.java:286)
>  [jwsc]     at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.javac(JwscTask.java:335)
>  [jwsc]     at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.compile(JwsModule.java:390)
>  [jwsc]     at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwsModule.build(JwsModule.java:262)
>  [jwsc]     at weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask.execute(JwscTask.java:227)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [jwsc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1249)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [jwsc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
>  [jwsc]     at com.bea.workshop.cmdline.antlib.AntExTask.execute(AntExTask.java:406)
>  [jwsc]     at com.bea.workshop.cmdline.antlib.AntCallExTask.execute(AntCallExTask.java:118)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [jwsc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
>  [jwsc]     at com.bea.workshop.cmdline.antlib.AntExTask.execute(AntExTask.java:406)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [jwsc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
>  [jwsc]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:217)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [jwsc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [jwsc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
>  [jwsc]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.IfTask.execute(IfTask.java:197)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [jwsc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.TaskAdapter.execute(TaskAdapter.java:154)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [jwsc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [jwsc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
>  [jwsc]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doSequentialIteration(ForTask.java:259)
>  [jwsc]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doToken(ForTask.java:268)
>  [jwsc]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.doTheTasks(ForTask.java:299)
>  [jwsc]     at net.sf.antcontrib.logic.ForTask.execute(ForTask.java:244)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [jwsc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [jwsc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:398)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [jwsc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1249)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>  [jwsc]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>  [jwsc]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1249)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
>  [jwsc]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
> ```
>
> [AntUtil.deleteDir] Deleting directory C:\DOCUME~1\KEVIN~1.BRE\LOCALS~1\Temp_5l950r

The Ant target that uses the `<jwsc>` task is this:

```
<target name="webservice.build" depends="init,generated.root.init">
  <path id="jwsc.srcpath">
    <path path="${java.sourcepath}" />
    <pathelement path="build/assembly/.src" />
  </path>

  <taskdef name="jwsc" classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.JwscTask" >
    <classpath> 
      <path refid="weblogic.jar.classpath" />
    </classpath> 
  </taskdef>

  <property name="jwsc.module.root" value="${project.dir}/build/weboutput"/>

  <property name="jwsc.contextpath" value="irWeb"/>

  <property name="jwsc.srcpath.prop" refid="jwsc.srcpath"/>

  <path id="jwsc.classpath">
    <path refid="weblogic.jar.classpath" />
    <path refid="java.classpath" />
    <pathelement path="${java.outpath}" />
  </path>

  <jwsc destdir="${project.dir}/build" classpathref="jwsc.classpath">
    <module name="weboutput" explode="true" contextPath="${jwsc.contextpath}" >
      <jwsFileSet srcdir="${webservices.dir}" type="JAXRPC"> 
        <include name="**/*.java"/>
      </jwsFileSet> 
      <descriptor file="${jwsc.module.root}/WEB-INF/web.xml" />
      <descriptor file="${jwsc.module.root}/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml" />
    </module>
  </jwsc>
</target>
```

I have no idea what could be causing the compiler to throw this error at build time, and a day of google searching has turned up other instances of this error caused by different triggers, and solutions for those propblems didn't work for me. I also found a single report on the Oracle forums that seemed to be a carbon copy of this issue, but there were no replies.

The application is written in Weblogic Workshop 10, runs on Weblogic Server 10.3, and uses Beehive / NetUI. Not sure if that would make a difference or not though. The build scripts were automatically generated by Weblogic Workshop, with some tweaks and fixes made to other aspects of the files by myself to fix other compatability issues. I am using Java 1.6.0_23 from Sun, and Ant 1.8.1

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

**~~~EDIT~~~**
Update: I found a workaround for this by changing the JDK on my system from Sun JDK to the JRockit JDK that ships with WebLogic. I guess JRockit has classes modified and optimised for WebLogic compared to the ones in the Sun JDK.

((Also, wasn't sure whether to put this in an edit or an answer, so opted for an edit. If this is the wrong place for this I apologise.))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error your experiencing is because your application (the ant task really) is attempting to access a class that has access restrictions on it.  That is why it will work for you with JRockit and not Sun.

There is probably an error in one of the supporting libraries.  You should probably do as it says and file a bug at the appropriate place.

Answer (score 2):

Use fork="true" on jwsc task. It solved this problem without switching to JRockit.